# Determine show/hide status of a given cell in a range

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I have a set of values set up as a range, and want to run a given action for each one of them.  This works:

```
Sub demo()
    For Each listitem in Sheets("Sheet").Range("List").Rows
        'Do stuff with listitem
    Next listitem
End Sub
```

The issue is, I'd like to add a bit of extra functionality; if I hide a given row, I'd like it to pick up on it and not process that row - something along these lines:

```
Sub demo()
    For Each listitem in Sheets("Sheet").Range("List").Rows
        If listitem.Visible Then
            'Do stuff with listitem
        End If
    Next listitem
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting `Object does not support this property or method` when I try that.

Presumably this is possible, so what command do I need to use to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `If listitem.Hidden=False` could work.

Comment: Hurrah, success.  I am bemused that the other doesn't though. :/